# Actionscript Loader.loadBytes() silently bails out, Complete Event never fired

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, arrays, loader

i am using the following setup:

1. i load a local file with FileReference.load() into the swf
2. then i user Loader.loadBytes() to parse the loaded ByteArray into BitmapData to pass it to a BitmapImage's source

step 1 works fine and i get the bytearray which is about 36k, according to the progressevent.

now i pass the the data as follows:
loader.loadBytes(event.payload as ByteArray);

here's where i'm stuck. i have listened both for Event and DataEvent but nothing happens. i enclosed the part in a try/catch statement, still nothing. i ran it with the debugger and: NOTHING. it just seems to do nothing after calling loadBytes.

i looked up a lot of threads about complete events not firing on loader, but nothing similar to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i gave up on this. it was probably my fault somewhere but i ended up just adding the loader itself and stopped trying to load the bytearray into a bitmapimage.

Comment: adding insult to injury i just saw that i wasn't listening on contentloaderinfo but on the loader itself. certified idiot!

Comment: Thank you! I was doing the same thing, apparently, and your post pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Its not your fault, i have had this issue now for 3 weeks and i absolutely need to get this to work. There is something going on with Loader when it tries to loadBytes. Ive tried sooo many attempts to solve / bypass this issue, still nothing :/

Answer (score 2):

To clarify what's discussed here (I just had the same problem) you need to attach the event listener to Loader.contentLoaderInfo, NOT Loader.